# regex for url validation using jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I need to validate the url using regex. The valid formats that should be accepted are as follows:

```
users.kathir.com
www.kathir.com
```

I am currently using the following regex:

```
^[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-])+(.[a-z])
```

But it accepts www.google as the valid one, but it should accept either google.com or www.google.com only. Please suggest

Comment: If you're only interested in capturing top-level domains that end in .com / .edu / etc., then you can literally place those characters to be validated in the last section. ...`.(com|edu)` rather than the character class `.[a-z]`. You should update your question to be very specific about what you want to validate rather than four examples only showing one example of an invalid URL

Answer (score 2):

I use this, works pretty well:

```
function checkUrl(url){
    return url.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?/);
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by user [will](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200910/will) also validate those regex in which there is no .com|edu|org etc at the end to make it more appropriate I have modify the regex which works fine for me and also want to share with you

```
var pattern = /^(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])+(.[a-z])?/;
var regex = new RegExp(pattern);
var website_url = $("#website_url").val();// url of the website
if (website_url.match(regex)) {
    return true
} else {
    return false;
}
```

if you like it do an Upvote